# Firebase no index defined

Tags: javascript, json, firebase

I'm using Firebase to retrieve some data of Users.
I need to retrieve **only one User** with (`gameSearching = true`).

My data looks like:

```
Users
|
|_____ John
|        |___ name: John Farmer
|        |___ gameSearching: true
|
|_____ James
|        |___ name: James Smith
|        |___ gameSearching: false
|
|_____ Barbara
         |___ name: Barbara Smith
         |___ gameSearching: true
```

I'm running this code:

```
setData(('Users/' + you + '/'), {gameSearching: true});

var ref = new Firebase("https://grootproject.firebaseio.com/Users");
var child = ref.orderByChild("gameSearching");
child.on("child_added", function (data) {
    var yourself = firebase.getAuth().password.email.split("@", 1)[0];
    data.forEach(
        function (childSnapshot) {
            if (childSnapshot[i].val().gameSearching == true && childSnapshot[i].key() != yourself) {
                var opponent = childSnapshot[i].key();

                setData(('Users/' + opponent + '/'), {gameSearching: false});
                setData(('Users/' + yourself + '/'), {gameSearching: false});
            }
        }
    );


});
```

Because 'data' has multiple values, I use 'data.forEach' to separate them. After that point I can set a 'return' on 'true' so I only will recieve one User with 'gameSearching: true'.

My firebase rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true,
    ".indexOn": "gameSearching"
  }
}
```

When I run this code I get the following error:

> *'Uncaught Error: No index defined for gameSearching'*

I have searched for setting a index on 'gameSearching' using '.indexOn' but not with any succes.
https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/guide/indexing-data.html

Does anyone have a example or a solution?

---

Edit:

I now got the following code:

```
var ref = new Firebase("https://grootproject.firebaseio.com/Users");
    ref.orderByChild("gameSearching").equalTo(true).limitToFirst(1).on("child_added", function (data) {
        var yourself = firebase.getAuth().password.email.split("@", 1)[0];

            var opponent = data.key();
            console.log(opponent);

            setData(('Users/' + opponent + '/'), {gameSearching: false});
            setData(('Users/' + yourself + '/'), {gameSearching: false});
            console.log('ja');
    });
```

I edited my rules of my firebase:

```
{
"rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true,
    "Users": {
  ".indexOn": "gameSearching"
}
}
```

}

The indexOn error wont show anymore, so that's great. But `ref.orderByChild("gameSearching").equalTo(true).limitToFirst(1`) will runs twice. I don't know how that's possible. I'm using limitToFirst(1)`, so I expect 1 child?

Comment: What do you mean by "not with any succes"? I've added plenty of indexes and it always works without problem. Can you show the relevant section of your rules? (click the edit link under your question to add the information, do **not** put it in a comment)

Comment: Note that the command is `.indexOn`, not `.indexOf` like you've typed above. If you made the same typo in your rules, it will indeed not work.

Comment: I mean .indexOn, sorry.
The problem I have is that I don't know where to place .indexOn

Comment: Which is why I asked you to add your rules to the question. That also gives you a chance to fix your typo. :-)

Comment: Ah ok, I see why your index is not created. I'll write up a second answer for that one, since the problems I highlighted in my initial answer are also relevant.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Now that you added your rules, it is clear what is wrong there.

These are your current rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true,
    ".indexOn": "gameSearching"
  }
}
```

So you allow everyone read and write access on your entire Firebase and tell it to add an index on `gameSearching`. The problem is that you've defined your index at the top-level, instead of at the level where it needs to be in your Firebase.

This is your current data structure:

```
{
    "Score" : {
        "sam_lous" : {
            "score" : 2
        }
    },
    "Users" : {
        "hallo" : {
            "gameSearching" : true
        },
        "sam_lous" : {
            "gameSearching" : true
        },
        "test" : {
            "gameSearching" : false
        },
        "test2" : {
            "gameSearching" : true
        }
    }
}
```

The `gameSearching` property exists only under children of the `Users` node. So that is where you should define your `.indexOn`:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true,
    "Users": {
      ".indexOn": "gameSearching"
    }
  }
}
```

With that, your index should be created (in my experience it happens straight away when you save your rules) and the error/warning message should disappear. But to fix the behavior, you should also make the changes that I put in my other answer.

*I have to admit that [Firebase's documentation on indexing your data](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/guide/indexing-data.html), could be clearer on where you define these `.indexOn` rules. If someone at Firebase is reading along, can you please add some better examples that highlight that `.indexOn` needs to be defined at the level where the data resides?*

Comment: Thx Frank van Puffelen! You helped me a lot!

Comment: Shouldn't the index actually be one-level deeper under `Users`? That's how I interpreted Firebase's documetation

Comment: Nope, it should be where I put it in my example. Check the linked documentation page and the data there too: the structure is `/dinosaurs/$dinosaur/height` and the `.indexOn` for `height` and `length` is on **`dinostaurs`** If you're having trouble generating the correct indexes in a use-case of your own, please open a new question and include a sample of your data and your (security) rules.

Answer (score 3):

Your query orders the data, but fails to filter it. If you change it to this, the query will only match users that are searching for a game:

```
var query = ref.orderByChild("gameSearching").equalTo(true);
```

This roughly translates to a SQL of `WHERE gameSearching = true`, which is what you asked in your previous question. Note that I called the variable `query`, because it represents a query on the data. Or if you want to stick to SQL metaphors, it is more similar to a VIEW in a relational database.

Since you're listening to `child_added` your function will be invoked once for each user that fits your query. So the `forEach` doesn't make any sense to me in your snippet. If you want to use a `forEach` you can get all users that match the query at once with the `value` event:

```
var searchers = ref.orderByChild("gameSearching").equalTo(true);
searchers.on('value', function(searchersSnapshot) {
    searchersSnapshot.forEach(function(snapshot) {
        console.log(snapshot.key());
    });
});
```

Which will currently log this on your Firebase:

> hallo
>
> sam_lous
>
> test2

You *can* also use `child_added` to accomplish the same, but in that case you don't need `forEach`:

```
var searchers = ref.orderByChild("gameSearching").equalTo(true);
searchers.on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
    console.log(snapshot.key());
});
```

*Fun fact: while `on('child_added'` triggers the Firebase WARNING of a missing index, `on('value'` does not. But either way: you should really add the index, because without that performance will suffer unacceptably as you add players.*

Since you indicate you only need one child, you can also limit the query further to just give you the first child:

```
var searchers = ref.orderByChild("gameSearching").equalTo(true).limitToFirst(1);
```

These and many other operations are covered in sections 2 - 5 of the [Firebase Web Guide](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/).