# indexOn not working on nested data

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I currently have a data structure that looks like this

```
Rooms
  -k-abcw2222
    Messages
      -k-112w12123 : {
        text : 'hello'
        msgdate : 1487558835433
      }
      -k-112w12125 : {
        text : 'hello2'
        msgdate : 1487558835633
      }
```

I want to listen to every new message published to a room and am doing a

```
firebase
  .database()
  .ref('/Rooms/' + roomkey + '/Messages/')
  .orderByChild('msgdate')
  .on(...)
```

but I get the exception

> No index defined for orderBy

I created the index as follows

```
{
  "rules" : {
    "Rooms" : {
      "$Roomsid" : {
        "Messages" : {
          ".indexOn": ["msgdate"]
        }
        ...
}
```

and also tried creating the index as follows

```
{
  "rules" : {
    "Rooms" : {
      "$Roomsid" : {
        "Messages" : {
          "$MessageId" : {
            ".indexOn": ["msgdate"]
          }
          ...
}
```

but still did not work. Any suggestions?

Comment: The first rules snippet appears to have the index specified correctly. Are you sure the rules have been published to the database?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27877612/firebase-no-index-defined

Comment: Yes, they have been published to the Database. I did hit the button, is there any other way to verify.