# How to define index in firebase realtime db rules?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to read all chatid's. As shown below in image.

[image: Firebase console image here]

I have following query:

```
firebase.database().ref("Messages/" + suid).orderByChild("chattingid").on("child_added", data => {
            data.forEach(snapshot => {
                console.log("You are here to see " + snapshot.val().chatid);
            })
})
```

And i am getting error on my console:

```
Error: No index defined for chattingid
```

My current firebase rule for index.

```
"Messages": {
          ".indexOn": "chattingid"
}
```

How to define indexing in firebase console? So that i dont get error as i have mentioned above. Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow .. Read this it can help you : https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/indexing-data

Comment: Thanks for sharing i already have read it and I have tried many times but still couldn't figured it out how to do it I just want to get all chatid as shown in image.

Comment: Great! .. read This answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27877612/firebase-no-index-defined

Comment: @KevinM.Mansour Not helpful. What you are suggesting by googling. I already did that a day ago.

Comment: Trying to help :) .. I do not google .. I just searching for answers in Stack Overflow that can help you .. as @FrankvanPuffelen observed some things about indexing in his answer .. Sorry for wasting your time I tried to help :)

Answer (score 0):

To log all `chatid` values for a given user:

```
firebase.database().ref("Messages/" + suid).on("value", data => {
  data.forEach(userBSnapshot => {
    userBSnapshot.child("chattingid").forEach(messageSnapshot => {
      console.log("You are here to see " + messageSnapshot.val().chatid);
    })
  })
})
```

So the changes are:

- I removed the `orderBy` call, as there's no ordering/filtering needed here.
- I listen for a "value" event, which makes the code a bit easier to reason about.
- That also means we need an extra loop in the callback function.
- We loop over the children of the `chattingid` snapshot.

Things to note:

- This still reads all `chat` nodes too, as there is no way to read part of each node. If your `chat` nodes are big, consider creating to top-level trees: one with the `chattingid` children and one with the `chat` children. Also see the Firebase documentation on [data structuring](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/structure-data#best_practices_for_data_structure).

To get rid of the error about a missing index, define the index as:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ...
    "messages": {
      ".indexOn": "chattingid/chatid"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Puff for detailed answer. I will create top-level tree/node for chattingid. But i still dont know why i am getting undefined with your query.

Comment: What is "your query"?

Comment: I using your answer's query. I am seeing on my console. You are here to see undefined (x2 times) as i have two chatid inside suid, as in my image.

Comment: As far as I can tell the code in my answer should work. If it doesn't for you, please edit your question to show what you've done with it - and what error you get.